# Performance impacts on specifying multiple columns in inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select some records from two tables based on matching the values of two columns.
I have got two queries for the same, out of these one contains join on two columns as:

```
    SELECT 
         *
    FROM
        USER_MASTER UM
    INNER JOIN
        USER_LOCATION UL
    ON 
        UM.CUSTOMER_ID=UL.CUSTOMER_ID AND UM.CREATED_BY=UL.USER_ID
```

and the same results can be achieved by following query having single column join as:

```
    SELECT 
            *
    FROM
        USER_MASTER UM
    INNER JOIN
        USER_LOCATION UL
    ON 
        UM.CREATED_BY=UL.USER_ID
    WHERE
        UM.CUSTOMER_ID=UL.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Is there any difference in performance of above queries?

Comment: can't you just run them and include the execution plan and assess the difference?

Comment: perhaps give this a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blogdoezequiel/archive/2012/01/15/t-sql-misconceptions-join-on-vs-where.aspx

Comment: I think a simply analogy should explain it better, Imagine if I ask you how many people in your company are same age as you, All you have to do is compare ages of everyone to your age pretty quick hmmm, now if I ask you how many people in your company are same age as you or Mr.X now you have to compare ages of all the poeple x2, So I wouldnt be surprised if it takes you a bit longer then before. I hope this makes a bit sense :)

Comment: Two semantically identical queries of this fashion will produce the exact same execution plan 10 times out of ten. Readability is another matter, and speaks strongly for explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

As everything concerning performance the answer is: It Depends.

In general the engine is smart enough to optimize both queries, I'm not surprised if both produce the same execution plan.

In fact you must run both queries a few times and study the execution plan to actually determine if both run about the same time **AND** using the same amount of CPU, IO and memory. (Remember performance is not only about running fast, is about smart use of all resources).

For a "semantic" vision, your data is using two keys to be "determined". In that case you can let both expression at the JOIN predicate. Let only filters at the WHERE clause.
The advantage of explicit joins over implicit ones is for create this logic (and visual) separation